# react-native string unwanted NewLine

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, typescript, react-native

So I have some code:

```
yield put(
    actions.recordActivityTag({
        key: "onboarding_answer_select",
        detail: {
            onboarding_answer_text:
                `confidence_facing_new_health_concern_score:${interviewInfo.scaleConfidenceHealthcare}`,
        },
    }),
)
```

And the line starting with `confidence_facing_new_health_concern` is not reading everything onto one line at a time. What I am getting as a return for the `recordActivityTag` is `confidence_facing_...` then a newline and then the score which is supposed to be appended onto one line. It should read

```
confidence...4
```

What I am getting is

```
confidence...
'4'
```

How can I get the strings to read all on one line instead of two?

Comment: Does interviewInfo.scaleConfidenceHealthcare have line break?

Comment: Unless `interviewInfo.scaleConfidenceHealthcare` contains whitespace, the output won't have any whitespace (since your template doesn't). But wherever you're outputting this to may put a break after the `:` depending on context and length; that can be controlled with CSS. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (They don't support TypeScript, so just leave out type annotations.)

Comment: Then there's a newline in the interpolated text, or an inaccurate code paste.

Comment: No there is no linebreak in the code. 'interviewInfo' is being read as it should be but '.scaleConfidenctHealthcare' is being read on a newline.